# Same-line vs. multi-lined bitwise operation discrepancy

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, integer-promotion

While writing a program for uni, I noticed that

```
unsigned char byte_to_write_1 = (0xFF << 2) >> 2; ==> 0xFF (wrong)
unsigned char byte_to_write_2 = (0xFF << 2);
byte_to_write_2 = byte_to_write_2 >> 2; ==> 0x3F (correct)
```

I don't understand what's causing the discrepancy... my best guess is that while modifying a byte with multiple operations on the same line, C "holds onto" the extra bits in a slightly larger datatype until the line is terminated so 0xFF << 2 is held as 11[1111 1100] instead of 1111 1100 so on the same-line shiftback, the result is 1111 1111 instead of 1111 1100.

What causes the difference in results? Thanks in advance...

I first noticed the issue in a larger code project but have been able to recreate the issue using a much more simple program.[image of simplified code to showcase problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0eyf.png)

Comment: Because your RHS operations on constants are done as `int` type (signed!). The second one is done after the result of first step was truncated to fit in `unsigned char`

Comment: It's interesting what OP deems to be 'correct'. At face value those labels are reversed, and with the use of constants is rather contrived. If the aim was to clear the top bit, then `byte_to_write &= 0x7F` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

> ```c
> unsigned char byte_to_write_1 = (0xFF << 2) >> 2;  // 0xFF
> ```

`0xFF` is an `int`. (Obtaining `0xFF` from an `unsigned char` wouldn't change anything since it would get promoted to an `int`.) `0xFF << 2` is `0x3FC`. `0x3FC >> 2` is `0xFF`.

---

> ```c
> unsigned char byte_to_write_2 = 0xFF << 2;  // 0xFC
> byte_to_write_2 >>= 2;                      // 0x3F
> ```

We've already established that `0xFF << 2` is `0x3FC`. But you assign that to an `unsigned char` which is presumably only 8 bits in size. So you end up assigning `0xFC` instead. (`gcc` warns about this if you enable warnings as you should.)

And of course, you get the desired value when you right-shift that.

---

Solutions:

```c
(unsigned char)( 0xFF << 2 ) >> 2
```

```c
( ( 0xFF << 2 ) & 0xFF ) >> 2
```

```c
0xFF & 0x3F
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s1Ef89cn5) on Compiler Explorer.

Comment: `0xFF` is definitely an `int`, but even if it were an `unsigned char`, it would still be subject to *promotion* to `int` in the context of the shift expression.  So, for example, although the desired behavior can be obtained by casting the *result* of the first shift, it cannot be obtained by casting either or both of the *operands* of that shift.  The types of the operands is a secondary issue.

Comment: @John Bollinger, yeah, I discovered that while writing my answer. Still, I felt that adding "what if we cast?" bit would be too much for the answer. Good as  a comment, though :)

Comment: @John Bollinger, Found a non-distracting way to add a mention of integer promition.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these two code snippets

```
unsigned char byte_to_write_1 = (0xFF << 2) >> 2; ==> 0xFF (wrong)
```

and

```
unsigned char byte_to_write_2 = (0xFF << 2);
byte_to_write_2 = byte_to_write_2 >> 2; ==> 0x3F (correct)
```

is that in the second code snippet there is used the variable `byte_to_write_2` to store the intermediate result of the expression `(0xFF << 2)`. The variable can not hold the full integer result. So the integer result is converted to the type `unsigned char` that can store only one byte.

The maximum value that can be stored in an object of the type `unsigned character` is `0xFF`

```
— maximum value for an object of type unsigned char
UCHAR_MAX 255 // 28 − 1
```

that is equal to `255`. While the expression `0xFF << 2` that is equivalent to `255 * 4` can not fit in an object of the type `unsigned char`.

In the first code snippet the intermediate result of the expression `(0xFF << 2)` has the type `int` due to the integer promotion and can be used without a change in the full expression `(0xFF << 2) >> 2`.

Consider the outputs of these two calls of `printf`

```
printf( "0xFF << 2 = %d\n", 0xFF << 2 );
printf( "( unsigned char )( 0xFF << 2 ) = %d\n", ( unsigned char )( 0xFF << 2 ) );
```

They are

```
0xFF << 2 = 1020
( unsigned char )( 0xFF << 2 ) = 252
```